# How to say "It depends on the context"?

Tags: предлоги

Will it be correct if I translate "It depends on the context" into "**Это зависит *от* контекста**"? I understand that always I have to use the preposition "от" rather than other prepositions (e.g. Это зависит *от* погода). Isn't it?

Comment: In spoken language you can simply say "нууу это завииисит…" with or without stretching out the vowels (to indicate the long ellipsis at the end) :)

Answer (score 10):

Зависит (verb) is used with the "fixed" preposition "от" followed by the genitive case - родительный падеж. Зависит от чего?

> зависит от контекста, от погоды, от него.